# Tomcat working fine on localhost, but got internal server error on deployment

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, web-services, tomcat

I developed web app on localhost, which works fine. But when I deployed it on server, it got me Internal Server Error when I try to create users

And when I run it using ./catalina.sh run, I got this

```
12-May-2018 22:48:17.984 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
12-May-2018 22:48:18.236 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12-May-2018 22:48:18.266 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:655)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1086)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:268)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
... 13 more

12-May-2018 22:48:18.279 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
12-May-2018 22:48:18.284 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:655)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1086)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:268)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
... 13 more
```

Address is here
http://128.199.228.4:8080/kuapp

POST method: http://128.199.228.4:8080/kuapp/users
with JSON content which got an internal server error

```
{
  "firstName": "Pakanon",
  "lastName": "Pantisawat",
  "email": "pakanon.pk@gmail.com",
  "password": "12345678",
  "userId": "b6010546891",
  "role": "student"
}
```

GET method: http://128.199.228.4:8080/kuapp/users which is work, but there's nothing in the db so it'll return empty array

Answer (score 1):

In the exception stack you can see:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

It means that the port to which Tomcat binds is already in use by some other process. The default port used by Tomcat is 8080.

You must kill the other process or change the port used by Tomcat. You can change the port editing `conf/server.xml` file, replacing 8080 with the desired port, for example, to set Tomcat to use port 8081:

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Answer (score -1):

It was caused by unknown exception in the code.

Comment: No, the exception is not unknown.